# how to render angular2 html page after rest webservice response comes

Tags: rest, angular, typescript

I can get rest webservice response and console it in screen without any problem. But unfortunately, in the page I can see initial value of the result of the werbservice call. What I need to do render the page after I get response from wbservice? I meant I can see userInfo and userName's initial values. You can see the snippet below.

Regards 
Alper

```
  export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
response:any;
errorMessage:any;
form:FormGroup;
obj = {"one": "", "two": "", "three": "", "four": ""};
webserviceUrl = "https://httpbin.org/post";
webServiceUrlGet = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
username = "alper"
userInfo = "alper Info";
componentName =  'AppComponent';

ngOnInit():void {
  this.getUserName();
}

 getUserName() {

this.http.get(this.webServiceUrlGet)
  .subscribe(
    function (data) {
      this.userInfo = data.json();
      this.username = this.userInfo.userId;


    },
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
return this.username;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what "render the page after I get response from wbservice" means. Please have a look at my answer. But I have doubts this is the whole story.

Comment: your answer is correct. I was using subscribe in a wrong way.Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This won't work

```
.subscribe(
  function (data)
```

It should be instead

```
.subscribe(
  (data) =>
```

for `this` to work inside the callback.

To only render the template when the response arrived you can for example use

```
<ng-container *ngIf="userInfo">
  <!-- actual template content here -->
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank you Günter.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the suggestion above to use fat arrows. An alternative may be to enclose 'this' in your closure as so:

```
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
    response:any;
    errorMessage:any;
    form:FormGroup;
    obj = {"one": "", "two": "", "three": "", "four": ""};
    webserviceUrl = "https://httpbin.org/post";
    webServiceUrlGet = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
    username = "alper"
    userInfo = "alper Info";
    componentName =  'AppComponent';

    ngOnInit():void {
        this.getUserName();
    }

    getUserName() {
        let that = this;
        this.http.get(this.webServiceUrlGet)
        .subscribe(
            function (data) {
                that.userInfo = data.json();
                that.username = that.userInfo.userId;
            },
        error => that.errorMessage = <any>error);
        return that.username; // Return statement not necessary
    }
}
```